# using a datatemplate for a list of listviewitems

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, binding, listviewitem

I've created a listview. The listview's source is set to a list of "listviewitem"s. The listviewItem's content is set to the specific class that I need data from.
Somehow, the datatemplate from my xaml document is not recognised which results in a default template instead of the one I defined.

My template looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Tiled">
    <StackPanel Height="100" Width="90">
        <Grid Width="70" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Content.Icon}" Margin="6,6,6,9"/>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock Style="{Binding Path=Content.Name}" FontSize="13" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,1" />
    </StackPanel>       
</DataTemplate>
```

I know that I can also set the source of the list to a collection of objects instead of listviewitems, but I need the contextmenu from the listviewitems.

Comment: How do you link this DataTemplte to listview column or you use ListBox I see you have x:Key="Tiled" but no point where you use it.

Comment: <ListView Name="viewComponent" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Tiled}" />

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I can also set the source of the list to a collection of objects instead of listviewitems, but I need the contextmenu from the listviewitems.

No you don't, that's what the [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) is for.

---

What you by the way should see in the output window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='ListBoxItem'

Comment: I don't really understand what you suggested solution is? Could you maybe rephrase how I can solve this?

Comment: In the item container style you can access the `ContextMenu` of the list view items. You hence have no need to have a collection of UI elements.